# Input clicked, add class Angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I have an array which produces a set of questions. It displays them as radio buttons.

Here is the HTML

```
          <div *ngSwitchCase="'radio'">
            <ul>
              <li
                *ngFor="let option of question.options"
                class="col-12 col-sm-6 p-0 purchase-type"
              >
                <input
                  class="form-control"
                  id="{{ option.id }}"
                  formControlName="{{ question.name }}"
                  value="{{ option.value }}"
                  type="radio"
                  (click)="clickEvent()" 
                  [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'"
                />
                <label for="{{ option.id }}" class="btn btn-choice {{ option.class }}">
                  <span class="hidden-xs">{{ option.id }} </span
                  ><span class="hidden-xs"> (</span> {{ option.label
                  }}<span class="hidden-xs">)</span></label
                >
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
```

Boolean inside the .ts

```
  status: boolean = false;
  clickEvent() {
    this.status = !this.status;
  }
```

As this is in an array, i'm struggling to toggle a class between each. At the moment, when I select any radio button, all radio button elements get the same class applied.

How would I only apply this to the radio button clicked?

Pretty new to Angular. Appreciate any help or suggestions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the goal of this? why do you use radio and toggle a class on a click event?

Comment: So I can add a class and show which is active

Comment: But why don't you style your input basend on let's say `:focus`? Question is what does active mean in your context? You want to style it somehow? Thing is that maybe there is a better solution than adding a class on click.

Comment: @Danny91 Can you provide stackblitz demo? will help

Comment: @Danny91 Check this :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hulrtz-jho8qk is that you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this should help you

```
<input
    class="form-control"
    id="{{ option.id }}"
    formControlName="{{ question.name }}"
    value="{{ option.value }}"
    type="radio"
    (click)="clickEvent($event)"  // add $event here
    [ngClass]="status ? 'success' : 'danger'"
/>
```

And in your component inject render. Make sure to check for your condition base on status variable

```
  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  clickEvent(event: any) {
    this.status ? 
    this.render.addClass(event.target,"active") : 
    this.render.removeClass(event.target,"active"); // set your class here
  }
```

Comment: Using renderer is like the last resort, it's not angular way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

If you have radio buttons you want to style once toggled (chosen), there are a few ways you could do it. One way would be as follows.

**Listen to the formControl Value**

```
<input [formControlName]="radio" value="value" [ngClass]="form.controls.get('radio').value == 'value' ? 'active' : 'inactive'"></input>
```

You could also make the radio input into a component.

**Component**

Then give it a generic template reference and check if it is checked.

(Warning: this one may be a little more complicated as you have to pass formControlName and fromGroup down, either as Inputs or implementing controlValueAccessor)

```
<input #radio [ngClass]="radio.checked ? 'active' : 'inactive'"></input>
```

Or you could call a function in typescript to resolve it as well.

**Function**

```
<input [formControlName]="radio" value="value" [ngClass]="checked(value) ? 'active' : 'inactive'"></input>

checked(value) {
    if(value == this.form.control['radio'].value) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }

}
```

I am sure there are other tidier ways as well, but hopefully the above is helpful.